# Unity game build: How to set Resolution higher than screen maximum?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm working on a project that does serverside rendering and thereby streams the images from a Windows 10 server (maximum resolution 1920x1080) to an Android 7 client (maximum resolution 2960x1440). The used framework is the TrinusVr library.

As I have understood, the Trinus framework streams whatever is in the game view to the client. In the Unity Editor I have the pleasure to be able to set any arbitrary resolution; of course when I put a resolution greater than what my screen can do, on the server side I see a scaled down version of the image in the game view. However, on the client it would use exactly this high resolution.

Now for the built game: Of course I tried using

```
Screen.SetResolution
```

to set high resolutions in the built game, too. Too high resolutions though will always be clamped down to the maximum resolution of my screen.

So is there any way, to have it like in the Unity Editor: a scaled down image on the server and the high resolution image on the client? 
Does anybody know another way to achieve this using the trinus lib?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use the camera's Target Eye parameter, combined with a higher resolution render texture. But then you'd need at least one more render pass to render the lower-resolution version, which could be too costly for VR.

Comment: I don't understand what the _TargetEye_ parameter has to do with my question; did you maybe intend the _TargetDisplay_ parameter?

Comment: Anyway, your answer is right: I now have a high resolution render texture which does what I needed. And since I'm doing serverside rendering the additional render pass is acceptable. If you explain what we need the _TargetEye_ parameter for, I will accept your answer as solution

Comment: It has been a while since I have worked in VR, but there used to be a dropdown in the inspector for the Camera component, and I believe it was called TargetEye. I do not see it in the docs anymore. I found a video of someone using it, so at least I didn't imagine it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crkpAZ9n4YE 
Glad that you were able to find an solution!

Comment: As for what I would use it for, I would send the full resolution version of the RT to the phone, then make another (orthographic) camera, set the Target Eye to `None (Main Display)` and have that camera output to the lower resolution display.

Comment: That's basically how I did it